# Pygame already installed; however, python terminal says "No module named 'pygame' " (Ubuntu 20.04.1)

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu, installation, pygame

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS. I have installed pygame with **sudo apt-get install python-pygame**. However, when I run my code using VS code, the python terminal gives the output below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "path", line 1, in <module>
    import pygame
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pygame'
```

I tried to reinstall Pygame using the same command. Here is the output:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
python-pygame is already the newest version (1.9.6+dfsg-2build1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 5 not upgraded.
```

Basically, I already have pygame installed. So what do you think might be the reason? My Python version is 3.8.2.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try `pip install pygame==2.0.0.dev10`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't a release build of pygame 1.9.6 for Python 3.8.2. Install a development version:

```
python3 -m pip install pygame==2.0.0.dev10
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I had been searching for a solution for two hours straight before posting the question here.